# How to find the result value

Tags: r, statistics

In the following results  How can I find the Estimate result value in R?
For example how can I find only the Estimation value of 'a1' or 'a4'?

This is the result of `summary(musc.2)`

```
summary(musc.2)    
Formula: Length ~ a[Strip] + b[Strip] * exp(-Conc/th)'    

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a1   23.4541     0.7962  29.456 4.96e-16 ***
a2   28.3020     0.7927  35.703  < 2e-16 ***
a3   30.8007     1.7156  17.953 1.73e-12 ***
a4   25.9211     3.0158   8.595 1.36e-07 ***
a5   23.2008     2.8912   8.025 3.50e-07 ***
a6   20.1200     2.4354   8.261 2.35e-07 ***
a7   33.5953     1.6815  19.979 3.04e-13 ***
a8   39.0527     3.7533  10.405 8.63e-09 ***
a9   32.1369     3.3175   9.687 2.46e-08 ***
a10  40.0052     3.3358  11.993 1.02e-09 ***
a11  36.1904     3.1095  11.639 1.60e-09 ***
a12  36.9109     1.8390  20.071 2.82e-13 ***
a13  30.6346     1.7004  18.016 1.64e-12 ***
a14  34.3118     3.4951   9.817 2.03e-08 ***
a15  38.3952     3.3749  11.377 2.27e-09 ***
a16  31.2258     0.8857  35.257  < 2e-16 ***
a17  31.2303     0.8214  38.019  < 2e-16 ***
a18  19.9977     1.0108  19.784 3.58e-13 ***
a19  37.0953     1.0706  34.650  < 2e-16 ***
a20  32.5942     1.1212  29.070 6.18e-16 ***
a21  30.3757     1.0570  28.738 7.48e-16 ***
b1  -27.3004     6.8732  -3.972 0.000985 ***
b2  -26.2702     6.7537  -3.890 0.001178 ** 
b3  -30.9011     2.2700 -13.613 1.43e-10 ***
b4  -32.2384     3.8100  -8.461 1.69e-07 ***
b5  -29.9406     3.7728  -7.936 4.07e-07 ***
b6  -20.6219     3.6473  -5.654 2.86e-05 ***
b7  -19.6246     8.0848  -2.427 0.026610 *  
b8  -45.7799     4.1131 -11.130 3.15e-09 ***
b9  -31.3446     6.3522  -4.934 0.000126 ***
b10 -38.5987     3.9555  -9.758 2.21e-08 ***
b11 -33.9211     3.8388  -8.836 9.19e-08 ***
b12 -38.2680     8.9920  -4.256 0.000533 ***
b13 -22.5683     8.1943  -2.754 0.013550 *  
b14 -36.1669     6.3576  -5.689 2.66e-05 ***
b15 -32.9521     6.3539  -5.186 7.44e-05 ***
b16 -47.2068     9.5403  -4.948 0.000122 ***
b17 -33.8746     7.6884  -4.406 0.000386 ***
b18 -15.8962     6.2222  -2.555 0.020508 *  
b19 -28.9690     7.2353  -4.004 0.000919 ***
b20 -36.9171     8.0325  -4.596 0.000257 ***
b21 -26.5075     7.0125  -3.780 0.001494 ** 
th    0.7969     0.1266   6.296 8.04e-06 ***
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summary(musc.2)$coefficients [1,1]` would give you a1 estimates 
`summary(musc.2)$coefficients [1,2]` would give you a2 estimates

...etc

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful @Justin Brousseau